# How to make script in linux use my interpteter and work? (#!)

Tags: c, linux, shell

I've made a simple shell for linux. It's reading line by line with getline() until ctrl+d (eof/-1) is entered into standard input.

While entering into stdin line by line code like that:

```
ls -al &
ls -a -l
```

My shell works pretty well.

I've tried to run script through my shell, but it's not working. When I execute script, my shell is automatically executed (1st line) but the shell do not interprete other lines.

```
#!/home/arbuz/Patryk/projekt/a.out
ls -al &
ls -a -l
```

What could cause it? I have to say that I'm very beginner in linuxes and teacher didnt say anything about all that stuff. Just a homework. I've done some researches but that's all I've found.

Here's code of my Shell. I've added shell path into etc/shells but its still not working

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{

    ssize_t bufer_size = 0;
    char* line = NULL;
    int line_size;

    while ((line_size = getline(&line, &bufer_size, stdin)) != -1) // while end of file
    {
        char** words_array;
        words_array = (char**)malloc(200 * sizeof(char*));

        int words_count = 0;
        int i;
        int j = 0;
        int words_length = 0;
        char word[100];
        for (i = 0; i < line_size; i++)
        {
            if (line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\n')
            {
                words_array[words_count] = (char*)malloc(words_length * sizeof(char));
                int b;
                for (b = 0; b < words_length; b++)
                {
                    words_array[words_count][b] = word[b];
                }
                j = 0;
                words_count++;
                words_length = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                word[j] = line[i];
                j++;
                words_length++;
            }
        }

        bool run_in_background = false;

        if (words_array[words_count - 1][0] == '&')
        {
            run_in_background = true;
            words_array[words_count - 1] = NULL;
        }

        int a = fork();

        if (a == 0) // child process
        {
            execvp(words_array[0], words_array);
        }
        else       // parent process
        {
            if (run_in_background == true)
            {
                printf("\n ---- running in background. \n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n ---- running normal \n");
                wait(NULL);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could be anything. Do you get any output at all?

Comment: Just my shell being run (so I can write script lines into stdin on my own)

Comment: Can you make a short example you could show us? See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: It should be listed in /etc/shells

Comment: @wildplasser `/etc/shells` lists valid login shells, any program can be run with a shebang.

Comment: @TimPost: the question was not very clear at that moment. But you are correct about the shebang.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your shell must accept command line arguments. In this case, your program will be called like this:

```
/home/arbuz/Patryk/projekt/a.out your_script
```

So you'll need a `main()` of this signature:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

and then parse the arguments. `argc` contains the amount of arguments. The script's filename is passed in `argv[1]`. You'll need to open it (using `fopen()`) and read commands from it instead of `stdin`. You should probably make sure that your shell ignores the first line of a file if it starts with a `#`.

If your script is called without an absolute path (a path that doesn't start with a `/`), then the filename is relative to the current directory. You can get that from the environment or programmatically with `getcwd()`.

Comment: He also has to tell his parser to ignore the shebang (and by extension, any line starting with `#`)

Comment: and what if script is in a different folder than a shell?, shall I put whole path to the shell in the place of your_script? Should I make a condition, that checks whether there's something in arguments (so it will write from file) or there's nothing (so it reads from stdin)?

Comment: @Patryk The current shell figures it out. For example, your shell can be invoked like this: `/home/arbuz/Patryk/projekt/a.out /tmp/your_script` The path is included in the argument. In this case, `argv[1]` will point to `/tmp/your_script`.

Comment: @Patryk Oh, you mean when you don't specify an absolute path to the script. In that case, you get the current directory from the environment. Specifically, from the `PWD` environment variable.

Comment: @Patryk Just a note, you probably want to run [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D%5Blinux%5D+title%3A+getopt_long) for a little help on dealing with arguments. Additionally, there is a [ccan module](http://ccodearchive.net/info/grab_file.html) that can help you deal with parsing the passed script.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that your shell reads from standard input, while a she-bang `#!` causes the script to passed as a command-line argument. So your shell is called as

```
/home/arbuz/Patryk/projekt/a.out <script>
```

... ignores the command line argument and waits for commands on standard input. You have to read the script from `argv[1]`.

Comment: is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @Patryk: yes, `fopen(argv[1], "r")` and read lines from that.